# I am converting annotated data(JSON) to COCO format while making Tensorflow Object detetction API, this is the error I am facing from last 2 days

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, annotations, object-detection-api

import os
import argparse
import json

from labelme import utils
import numpy as np
import glob
import PIL.Image

class labelme2coco(object):
def **init**(self, labelme_json=["new_images\Train"],
save_json_path="new_images\Train_Coco/coco.json"):
"""
:param labelme_json: the list of all labelme json file paths
:param save_json_path: the path to save new json
"""
self.labelme_json = labelme_json
self.save_json_path = save_json_path
self.images = []
self.categories = []
self.annotations = []
self.label = []
self.annID = 1
self.height = 0
self.width = 0

```
    self.save_json()

def data_transfer(self):
    for num, json_file in enumerate(self.labelme_json):
        with open(json_file, "r") as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
            self.images.append(self.image(data, num))
            for shapes in data["shapes"]:
                label = shapes["label"].split("_")
                if label not in self.label:
                    self.label.append(label)
                points = shapes["points"]
                self.annotations.append(self.annotation(points, label, num))
                self.annID += 1

    # Sort all text labels so they are in the same order across data splits.
    self.label.sort()
    for label in self.label:
        self.categories.append(self.category(label))
    for annotation in self.annotations:
        annotation["category_id"] = self.getcatid(annotation["category_id"])

def image(self, data, num):
    image = {}
    img = utils.img_b64_to_arr(data["imageData"])
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    img = None
    image["height"] = height
    image["width"] = width
    image["id"] = num
    image["file_name"] = data["imagePath"].split("/")[-1]

    self.height = height
    self.width = width

    return image

def category(self, label):
    category = {}
    category["supercategory"] = label[0]
    category["id"] = len(self.categories)
    category["name"] = label[0]
    return category

def annotation(self, points, label, num):
    annotation = {}
    contour = np.array(points)
    x = contour[:, 0]
    y = contour[:, 1]
    area = 0.5 * np.abs(np.dot(x, np.roll(y, 1)) - np.dot(y, np.roll(x, 1)))
    annotation["segmentation"] = [list(np.asarray(points).flatten())]
    annotation["iscrowd"] = 0
    annotation["area"] = area
    annotation["image_id"] = num

    annotation["bbox"] = list(map(float, self.getbbox(points)))

    annotation["category_id"] = label[0]  # self.getcatid(label)
    annotation["id"] = self.annID
    return annotation

def getcatid(self, label):
    for category in self.categories:
        if label == category["name"]:
            return category["id"]
    print("label: {} not in categories: {}.".format(label, self.categories))
    exit()
    return -1

def getbbox(self, points):
    polygons = points
    mask = self.polygons_to_mask([self.height, self.width], polygons)
    return self.mask2box(mask)

def mask2box(self, mask):

    index = np.argwhere(mask == 1)
    rows = index[:, 0]
    clos = index[:, 1]

    left_top_r = np.min(rows)  # y
    left_top_c = np.min(clos)  # x

    right_bottom_r = np.max(rows)
    right_bottom_c = np.max(clos)

    return [
        left_top_c,
        left_top_r,
        right_bottom_c - left_top_c,
        right_bottom_r - left_top_r,
    ]

def polygons_to_mask(self, img_shape, polygons):
    mask = np.zeros(img_shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = PIL.Image.fromarray(mask)
    xy = list(map(tuple, polygons))
    PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(mask).polygon(xy=xy, outline=1, fill=1)
    mask = np.array(mask, dtype=bool)
    return mask

def data2coco(self):
    data_coco = {}
    data_coco["images"] = self.images
    data_coco["categories"] = self.categories
    data_coco["annotations"] = self.annotations
    return data_coco

def save_json(self):
    print("save coco json")
    self.data_transfer()
    self.data_coco = self.data2coco()

    print(self.save_json_path)
    os.makedirs(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(self.save_json_path)), exist_ok=True
    )
    json.dump(self.data_coco, open(self.save_json_path, "w"), indent=4)
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="labelme annotation to coco data json file."
)
parser.add_argument(
    labelme_images="new_images\Train",
    help="Directory to labelme images and annotation json files.",
    type=str,
)
parser.add_argument(
    "--output", help="Output json file path.", default="new_images\Train_Coco/coco.json"
)
args = parser.parse_args()
labelme_json = glob.glob(os.path.join(args.labelme_images, "*.json"))
labelme2coco(labelme_json, args.output)
```

**Error which I am getting**
[Type-Error and redirecting to argparse library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5nLD.png)

**The tutorial I am following is also attached** [Train a Mask R-CNN model with the Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/train-a-mask-r-cnn-model-with-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below correction:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="labelme annotation to coco data json file."
)
parser.add_argument(
    "labelme_images",
    help="Directory to labelme images and annotation json files.",
    type=str,
)
parser.add_argument(
    "--output", help="Output json file path.", default="new_images\Train_Coco/coco.json"
)
args = parser.parse_args()
labelme_json = glob.glob(os.path.join(args.labelme_images, "*.json"))
labelme2coco(labelme_json, args.output)
```